# Tools to find memory use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, memory-leaks

In the Chrome task manager I'm noticing that my app is using around 75,000k memory, which seems a little high.  Is there a tool which will show the objects that are in memory, so that I can identify where I am misusing objects, or possibly even leaking memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Chrome DOM Inspector, you can click `Profiles` -> `Snapshot`. It gives you an idea of the memory map of your page, what uses how much and etc, including reference count and object size.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked before: [Javascript memory profiler for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171565/javascript-memory-profiler-for-firefox)

Take a look at Mozilla's performance tools: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/performance/tools.html