# Javascript profiler for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, profiler

I am having difficulty profiling Javascript in Firefox. We have a GWT based application which consumes huge memory( goes up to 1.5 Gigs) in FF, with the same set of operations, in IE, the memory usage remains under 800 MB. While IE has a really good profiler that shows memory leak suspects, I don't find any equivalent add-on for FF. The built-in profiler in FF shows the timings but I don't find memory related info. I went through an old SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171565/javascript-memory-profiler-for-firefox) talking about the same requirement but the links provided in the answers are either obsolete or don't provide accurate information. Couple of tools I found like Memchaser etc. show only the total memory consumed by the page, not the detailed info about which JS object is involved. I have tested with FF 31 and 40 and the behaviour remains same. Is anyone aware a tool that could help me here?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you link me to how it is done in IE please. If no one posts how I'll give you how I profile js, its a little bumpy and not a smooth experience but it works. But I don't think I do it the recommended way, if no one shows how, I'll share my method.

Comment: In IE, you can go to Developer tools from settings or F12, in the new window you will see a Memory tab that shows the details. This is in IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the latest nightly download? It is still in progress but may be what you are looking for.
[enable mem records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ4Ek.png)

Comment: Sounds like this could help us. Captures good details. Thanks Jason.